# Resolving dig command issue in linux

Tags: linux, dig

Please help me in resolving the dig command issue in my machine: Ubuntu 18.04.
Here's what the output comes when I run

> dig google.com
>
> output --->
>
> source lang: en ----> target lang: zh-CN google.com

[image]

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Answer (score 0):

actually it was my fault:
Solution:
Run the following commands:

> pip uninstall dig
>
> sudo apt intall dnsutils